# count on multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
Players
- id
- name

Games
- id
- game_type_id
- season_id


Goals
- player_id
- game_id

Assists
- player_id
- game_id
```

I've been struggling trying to build a query/view that will give me the players' goal and assist counts for each season and game type. It's important to each player is listed for each season and game type, whether they have goals/assists or not.

The query will be used to create a view. Can it be done in one query?

UPDATE: Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8312c) with some production sample data.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, it can be done. You'll need LEFT OUTER JOINs between the tables that might not have matching rows. That should get you started.

Comment: you also seem to be missing a table in there for `GameType`

Comment: The `GameType` table doesn't really matter, since all I need is the id of the game type which is found in the `Games` table.

I will try to get something up in SQL Fiddle shortly.

Comment: also, do both `Goals` and `Assists` have a missing value (like the total number of goals in that game for that player) or would you have multiple entries for `player_id` and `game_id` if a player had multiple goals in a game?

Comment: Multiple values for player_id and game_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT
    players.id,
    players.name,
    games.season_id,
    games.game_type_id,
    sum(CASE WHEN g.goals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.goals END) AS goals,
    sum(CASE WHEN a.assists IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.assists END) AS assists
FROM players
CROSS JOIN games
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    game_id, player_id,
    count(*) AS goals
  FROM goals
  GROUP BY
    game_id, player_id
) g ON
    g.player_id = players.id
    AND g.game_id = games.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    game_id, player_id,
    count(*) AS assists
  FROM assists
  GROUP BY
    game_id, player_id
) a ON
    a.player_id = players.id
    AND a.game_id = games.id
GROUP BY
    players.id,
    players.name,
    games.season_id,
    games.game_type_id
```

This isn't very short version, but it should be right now.

Comment: I'm seeing some inconsistencies using your query with my data. Here's an [example data set](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8312c/6). You'll notice from the first query and yours, the goal counts don't match up.

Comment: @YanSarazin you're right, it's my mistake! the root of it is in second left join - it clones rows. I think the first answer doesn't have this mistake.

Comment: Random checks across the whole data set and nothing seems out of place. Thanks!

Comment: So, I think I've just realized that this is some kind of classroom assignment, right? I've seen the same question asked multiple times now. In fact I answered it over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27339965/618649) in a slightly different way. It would be interesting to compare the performance of both solutions. But is there an ethical issue with getting a classroom assignment flat-out answered here?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  players.id,
  players.name,
  games.season_id,
  games.game_type_id,
  SUM(COALESCE(assists.rows, 0))             AS assists,
  SUM(COALESCE(goals.rows,   0))             AS goals
FROM
  players
CROSS JOIN
  games
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT game_id, player_id, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM assists GROUP BY game_id, player_id) AS assists
    ON assists.game_id = games.game_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT game_id, player_id, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM goals   GROUP BY game_id, player_id) AS assists
    ON goals.game_id   = games.game_id
GROUP BY
  players.id,
  players.name,
  games.season_id,
  games.game_type_id
```

But it may improve in performance if you had a `Seasons` table and a `GameType` table.

```
SELECT
  players.id,
  players.name,
  seasons.id,
  game_types.id,
  SUM(COALESCE(assists.rows, 0))             AS assists,
  SUM(COALESCE(goals.rows,   0))             AS goals
FROM
  players
CROSS JOIN
  seasons
CROSS JOIN
  game_types
LEFT JOIN
  games
    ON  games.season_id = seasons.id
    AND games.game_type = game_types.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT game_id, player_id, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM assists GROUP BY game_id, player_id) AS assists
    ON assists.game_id = games.game_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT game_id, player_id, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM goals   GROUP BY game_id, player_id) AS assists
    ON goals.game_id   = games.game_id
GROUP BY
  players.id,
  players.name,
  seasons.id,
  game_types.id
```

Comment: bah! beat me to it. wouldn't the left joins need to also be on `player_id`?

Comment: Had to fix a few typos to get this query to run, but the counts are all off. I've updated my question with an SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select p.id,
  p.name,
  gm.season_id,
  gm.game_type_id,
  sum(gl.goalcount),
  sum(a.AssistCount)
from players p
left join
(
  select game_id, player_id, count(*) GoalCount
  from goals
  group by game_id, player_id
) gl
  on p.id = gl.player_id
left join
(
  select game_id, player_id, count(*) AssistCount
  from assists
  group by game_id, player_id
) a
  on p.id = a.player_id
left join games gm
  on gl.game_id = gm.id
  and a.game_id = gm.id
where season_id is not null
group by p.id,
  p.name,
  gm.season_id,
  gm.game_type_id
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8312c/34)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, I didn't think of the cross join, I came up with:

select 
   players.id, games.game_type_id, games.season_id, g.c, a.c 
from players

left join (select count(id) as c, player_id, game_id from goals group by player_id, game_id) as g on g.player_id = players.id

left join (select count(id) as c, player_id, game_id from assists group by player_id, game_id) as a on a.player_id = players.id

right join games on games.id = g.game_id and games.id = a.game_id
group by players.id,  games.game_type_id, games.season_id;